# Using Spring Mobile device detection before Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I want to redirect users to a different page after login depending on what type of user they are, and if they're on a mobile device. My project uses Spring MVC and Spring Security. To get the redirect logic working, I use a Spring Security AuthenticationSuccessHandler to identify the type of user post-login and direct them to the correct page.

I was hoping to use Spring Mobile to check at this point whether they're on a mobile device, and if so send them to the mobile version of the URL. However, it seems that interceptors such as DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor get executed *after* the Spring Security filters, and so the resolution hasn't happened at the point I need it to.

At the moment, the only solution I can see to this is to disable the interceptor and instead directly use LiteDeviceResolver's resolveDevice() method. This feels a little bit hacky, but I can't see another obvious choice.

Is there any better way to configure this people are aware of?

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor() {
        return new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor()).order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

    }

}



    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        boolean isMobile = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request) != null
                && DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request).isMobile();

...
```